# Perturb/change a label vector with some percentage

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I was wondering if there was an efficient or optimal way to slightly change a label vector by some amount (governed by a random percentage).

To setup the problem, here's what I have.

```py
import numpy as np

num_classes = 4
batch_size = 12
sequence_length = 9

percentage = .6

labels = np.random.default_rng(0).integers(
  num_classes, size=(batch_size, sequence_length))
```

The label vector looks like:

```
>>> labels
array([[3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2],
       [0, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3],
       [3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2],
       [1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1],
       [1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1],
       [3, 1, 3, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0]])
```

To perturb the labels, I thought of making a masking matrix:

```py
mask = np.zeros_like(labels)
mask[..., :round(percentage*sequence_length)] = 1
mask = np.apply_along_axis(np.random.permutation, -1, mask)
```

That looks like:

```
>>> mask
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

At this point, I'm not sure what the next step is; but basically, where the mask==1, I want to perturb the labels. This means that Class 1 could be changed to either Class 0 or Class 2. The border classes should only be perturbed in one direction—Class 0 should only change up to Class 1 and Class 3 can only come down to Class 2.

The goal of this function should be to essentially change the classes with 60% chance.

Could anyone provide suggestions of how this is best done in NumPy?